# Possible to specify form attributes with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am looking for a way to specify POST attribute data to an Ajax.ActionLink. My best guess is something along these lines:

```
Ajax.ActionLink( "My Link", 
                 "SomeAction", 
                 "SomeController", 
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, 
                 { myParameter = "myValue" } )
```

Unfortunately, this results in the adding of `&myParameter=myValue` to the URL.

In case it is of any relevance, I'm ultimately trying to inject the anti forgery token into the request via the `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter.

Comment: Check out this resource - its worked like a charm for me... http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2010/05/22/anti-forgery-request-recipes-for-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax.aspx doesnt just ajax.actionlink rather a hand crafted $ajax statement

Comment: I was hoping to use something that relied on the existing helper function architecture. Perhaps I'm better off moving to the jQuery domain for this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the action methods, you are at the mercy of how it implements them.  The alternative is to use JQuery, which gives you full control over the process, to post the data via:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "..",
  data { myParameter: "myvalue" },
  .
  .
});
```

Comment: You are correct if you are referring to `Html.ActionLink`, however, the example I provided of `Ajax.ActionLink` does indeed use the POST verb when `HttpMethod = "Post"` is specified. In fact. `$.ajax` is ultimately triggered when it is clicked via unobtrusive ajax.

Comment: Looking over the unobtrusive ajax, it seems as though there is not a way to set the data attribute for `Ajax.ActionLink`. I ended up building my own helper function that ultimately uses `$.ajax`. Not what I was hoping for, but your suggestion seems to be the closest to correct as possible.